# HTML in WooCommerce product-attributes

Tags: html, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to allow Woocommerce to work with html within product attributes, so that for instance an attrbitue like PDF can link to a URL of a PDF.

Sample of the content of this attribute would be:
[ a target ="_blank"href="http://dmpscores.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/ckh-20/ckh-20.pdf">PDF ]

This is not possible now. I know there are workarounds to put this attribute in another tab, but than there is the problem of batch-import of - in this case - 5000 products and not being able to import it to the right tab.

I think it is a serious issue that WooCommerce doesn't allow html in product attributes. This would make the plugin much more better.

Who has a solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you attach a custom field to the WooCommerce product page? You'd then have to override the WooCommerce templates by copying the appropriate one(s) to your theme directory, and add markup as needed. Maybe that would even work without the custom field and just editing the template file itself (albeit more complicated)?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not very clear to me. Can you give an example?